# Hazelcast caching not works if manual CacheManager is added in the class

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

Hazelcast is configured in the spring boot (embedded hazelcast one)

```
@Bean
CacheManager hazelcastCacheManager() {
    return new HazelcastCacheManager(Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance());
}

@Bean
public Config hazelCastConfig() {

    Config cacheConfig = new Config().setInstanceName("cache-instance");

    MapConfig userCache = new MapConfig().setName("users")
            .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(500, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(12);
    cacheConfig.addMapConfig(userCache);

}
```

When I am using @Cacheable in the service layer, it is working fine (it remove key from cache after 12 sec)

```
@Cacheable(key = "#name", value = "users")
```

But, once I add CacheManager to the same service class. This cache value is never getting removed (above one). My final requirement is to use cache manager to get the cache & check if the value exists. (block user after 2nd try & allow after 12 sec. So, Cache will store it for 12 sec & I can check if not in the cache, proceed, else inform to wait)

```
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;

@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@Override
public void doCachingOperation() throws InterruptedException {

    Cache userCache = cacheManager.getCache("users");
    System.out.println(CalendarUtils.getCurrentDate());
    userCache.put("Satish", 1);
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(userCache.get("Satish").get().toString()));

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("2 sec passed");
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(userCache.get("Satish").get().toString()));

    Thread.sleep(14000);
    System.out.println("16 sec passed");
    System.out.println(CalendarUtils.getCurrentDate());
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(userCache.get("Satish").get().toString()));

}
```

Now, this value is still available after 16sec, whereas it was supposed to be removed with the key "Satish" after 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating a new instance without any configuration
`Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()` you should auto-wire the `HazelcastInstance`, let spring boot create the instance using the `hazelCastConfig()` bean.

```
@Autowired
private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

@Bean
CacheManager hazelcastCacheManager() {
    return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
}

@Bean
public Config hazelCastConfig() {

    Config cacheConfig = new Config().setInstanceName("cache-instance");

    MapConfig userCache = new MapConfig().setName("users")
            .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(500, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(12);
    cacheConfig.addMapConfig(userCache);

}
```

Comment: if that's the case, then better to use direct injectiion. @Bean
 CacheManager hazelcastCacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
  return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
 }